# "Ser" vs. "estar" with continuous actions, i.e. present participle

Tags: gramática, verbos, tiempos-verbales-progresivos

This is a "contextual" translation I just found online a few minutes ago:

> *Cariño, eres un poco empezando a preocuparnos un poco.*
>
> **Honey, you're kind of starting to worry us a little.**

The source of this translation is [contexto.reverso.net](http://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/poco).

My question is: Why are we using *ser* instead of *estar* in this construct? While learning Spanish, I was taught that present participle in the context of continuous action always takes *estar* because of the temporal nature of the said action. Why are we, then, making an exception here?

Comment: From this sample, I would advise you not to trust that translator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sentence is wrong, the correct translation would be:

> Cariño, estás empezando a preocuparnos un poco.

This fits what you were taught, which is right and proper.

Comment: There are no exceptions to the rule learned by Amit: always use the verb *estar* with continuous actions.